# About a homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let us consider a homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ transforming a point  $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ into a point  $(2x+4y, 3x+6y)$.

A) prove that the groups $\ker(\phi)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2/\ker(\phi)) $ both are isomorphic 
to $\mathbb{R}$.

B) is $\phi$ an automorphism ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Note that $\ker(\phi)=\{ (-2y,y)\;:\; y\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Is $f:\mathbb{R} \to \ker(\phi)$ given by $f(y):=(-2y,y)$ an isomorphism?

Comment: ..yes this is isomorphism

Comment: @Murali Well done. Any further doubt?

Comment: ..i am ok with one-ome ..i have dought with onto ..can you expalin

Comment: $f$ is onto because $2x+4y=0$,  $3x+6y=0$ implies that $x=-2y$.

Comment: @RobertZ..can you give me solution..

Comment: @Murali I gave you a hint. Now it is your turn.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Note that the image of $\phi$ is $\mathbb R (1,\frac32)$.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix of the homomorphism (linear map) is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4 \\
3 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has rank $1$. Thus the image of $\phi$ has dimension $1$ and, by the rank-nullity theorem, also $\ker\phi$ has dimension $1$. Vector spaces with the same dimension are isomorphic.